# Showing join table field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

#### Here I want to show the extra attribute CONFIRMED from the employments join table. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base    
has_many :employments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :employments

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :employments 
has_many :jobs, :through => :employments


class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
belongs_to :user  # Employment has an extra attribute of confirmed ( values are 1 or 0)
```

In my job view I want to show the confirmed value for each job.  I just cant seem to get it.
In my view i have:

```
<% @job.each do |job| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle('oddrow', 'evenrow') %>">
      <td><%= link_to job.clientname, job_url(job.id) %></td>
      <td><%= job.eventtype.name %></td>
      <td><% unless job.starts_at.blank? %><%= job.starts_at.to_formatted_s(:full) %><% end %></td>
      <td>7 - 12 </td>
```

#### Here I want to show the extra attribute CONFIRMED from the employments join table. What am I doing wrong?

```
     <td><%= job.employment.confirmed %></td> 
     </tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at your Job model. You've declared it to have many employments. Calling the plural form of the association (employments) will get you a list of the employments for that job.

If you wanted only the confirmed jobs, you could add a named scope to Employment like the following:

```
named_scope :confirmed, :conditions => ['confirmed = ?', true]
```

Then calling `job.employments.confirmed` would give you only the confirmed employments.

Comment: Jared,

I know I am missing somthing here.  I just cant seem to wrap my head around it.

<%=  job.employments.confirmed %> 
I get undefined method `confirmed' for #<Class:0x23110e4>

Comment: Since .employments is defined as has_many, it's going to return an array of all employments - and .confirmed doesn't make sense on an array. You need to loop through the returned employments and display each one; that, or if a job will only ever have one employment, the relationship should be redefined as a has_one.

Comment: Awesome.  named_scope worked well.  I just need to think of it a different way.  
named_scope makes more since